# Failed to use Regions.AP_SOUTH_1 sending raw email with AWS SES on Android

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-simple-email-service

I use the following java code to send user emails, it works as expected if I use Regions.US_EAST_1 and related identity pool id.

```
AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsyncClient client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceAsyncClient(new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(context, identityPoolId, Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));
client.sendRawEmailAsync(new SendRawEmailRequest(rawMessage), new AsyncHandler<SendRawEmailRequest, SendRawEmailResult>()
{
    @Override
    public void onError(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(SendRawEmailRequest request, SendRawEmailResult sendEmailResult)
    {
    }
});
```

But after I changed the region to **AP_SOUTH_1**, I also changed the identity pool id, the code stopped to work, the email will not be sent, and I started to see log saying

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: The security token included in
>   the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status
>   Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId; Request ID:
>   1168c9c2-a940-4bef-be36-8568787bc130)

Why US_EAST_1 works but AP_SOUTH_1 not? How to get the region AP_SOUTH_1 work? How can I identify and fix this problem?

Important note:
I have verified the sender email address in both regions.
I have granted the role ses:sendRawEmail permission.

Comment: Your sending user probably exists and is verified in us-east-1 but not in ap-south-1.

Comment: @jordanm I have verified the email address in both regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to post my 2 days investigation and found to help others:

Tested with

- AWS SDK for Android:

Using the latest adk `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ses:2.16.12'`, you can only use us-east-1, us-west-2, eu-west-1 3 regions to succeed in sending emails in production, unfortunately ap-south-1 is not on the list, even the SES console page shows you can use more regions, if you do it by code, you will always get the AmazonServiceException saying `The security token included in the request is invalid.`

- AWS SDK for Java:

Using the latest adk `implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:1.11.789'`, users can use Region ap-source-1 to send raw emails.